# How can I make a custom ArrayAdapter with a TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, autocompletetextview, tablayout

I am programming an app that can execute many commands with one click.
In the setting, for the command selection I use a AutoCompleteTextView with a TabLayout menu.

[current menu I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILOAK.png)

Here is the code:

```
        AutoCompleteTextView type = holder.type;
    type.setText(command.getType().getName(), false);

    String[] commandList = CommandType.getNames();

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Test");
    SelectionAdapter selectionAdapter =
            new SelectionAdapter(type, this.context, list);
   // ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.context,
           // R.layout.type_selection_item, commandList);
    type.setAdapter(selectionAdapter);
```

SelectionAdapter Class:

```
public class SelectionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Context context;
private RecyclerView items;
private CommandCategory category;
private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

public SelectionAdapter(AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView,
                        @NonNull Context context, ArrayList<String> test) {
    super(context, 0, test);
    this.context = context;
    this.autoCompleteTextView = autoCompleteTextView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View covertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.command_selection, parent,
            false);
    TabLayout tabLayout = rowView.findViewById(R.id.commandselection_categories);
    CommandCategory[] categories = CommandCategory.values();
    this.category = CommandCategory.GENEREAL;

    for (CommandCategory category : categories) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.newTab();
        tab.setText(category.getName());
        tabLayout.addTab(tab);
    }

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            category = CommandCategory.getTypeByName(tab.getText().toString());
            onCategoryChange();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    this.items = rowView.findViewById(R.id.commandselection_items);
    GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),
            2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    this.items.setLayoutManager(manager);


    CommandType[] types = CommandType.values();

    ArrayList<CommandType> typesOfCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CommandType type : types)
        if (CommandType.getCategory(type) == this.category)
            typesOfCategory.add(type);

    SelectionItemsAdapter adapter = new SelectionItemsAdapter(this.autoCompleteTextView,
            this.context, typesOfCategory);
    this.items.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}

private void onCategoryChange() {

    CommandType[] types = CommandType.values();
    ArrayList<CommandType> typesOfCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CommandType type : types)
        if (CommandType.getCategory(type) == this.category)
            typesOfCategory.add(type);

    SelectionItemsAdapter selectionItemsAdapter = (SelectionItemsAdapter) this.items.getAdapter();

    selectionItemsAdapter.updateItems(typesOfCategory);
    selectionItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


} }
```

The SelectionItemsAdapter Class:

```
public class SelectionItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectionItemsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<CommandType> types;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

public SelectionItemsAdapter(AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView, Context context, ArrayList<CommandType> commandTypes) {
    this.types = commandTypes;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.autoCompleteTextView = autoCompleteTextView;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.type_selection_item, parent, false);

    return new SelectionItemsAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CommandType type = types.get(position);
    TextView textView = holder.nameView;
    textView.setText(type.getName());

}

public void updateItems(ArrayList<CommandType> types) {
    this.types = types;
    System.out.println("ItemCount: " + types.size());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return types.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    TextView nameView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        this.constraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.type_layout);
        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(view.getContext(), this);
        this.nameView = view.findViewById(R.id.type_item);

        this.nameView.setOnClickListener( event -> {
            CommandType type = types.get(getAdapterPosition());
            autoCompleteTextView.setText(type.getName());
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }


}}
```

The problem I have is that when I update the RecyclerView the changes don't become visible.
[items doesn't change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2t8B.png)

With debugging I could see that the problem is in the SelectionAdapter class in the onCategoryChange() method.
Actually I also found the "solution" to this problem, if I add `this.notifyDataSetChanged();` to the onCategoryChange() method and also change some code in the getView method, then I can navigate with the tablayout.
But then I have another problem, then the Tablayout doesn't work as it should.
Like the click animation will be cancelled and if you would click on a tab that isn't fully visible, then normally it would be set completely visible, but that doesn't work too.

How can I fix both my problems?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the issue properly, but you could check using *notifyItemChanged(...)* and related methods instead of *notifyDataSetChanged()* because you don't want to reload all items in the RecyclerView. Maybe it would help.

Comment: Actually I want to reload all items because I am switching between categories with different types of commands. 
The problem are not the notify methods in the RecyclerView, the problem is the ArrayAdapter. 
Unfortunately this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution to this problem with an ArrayAdapter and an AutoCompleteTextView.
But it was possible with a Spinner.
So I created a custom spinner adapter that implements SpinnerAdapter and now it works!
This is not an easy solution but unfortunately I couldn't find a easy one at all.